# Losing punctuation/encoding after converting data to data.frame

Tags: r, encoding, dataframe

Could somebody explain me following:

```
#I am requesting data parsed from XML (console output)
> rss.title
[1] "Amerika je znepokojená expanziou Číny v Juhočínskom mori"                             
[2] "Pápež František označil palestínskeho prezidenta za anjela mieru"                     
[3] "Najlepšie reklamy Slovenska. Pozrite si výsledky súťaže Zlatý klinec 2015" 

#checking class (console output)
> class(rss.title)
[1] "character"

#creating data.frame (console output)
data.frame(rss.title)
1  Amerika je znepokojená expanziou Cíny v Juhocínskom mori
2  Pápež František oznacil palestínskeho prezidenta za anjela mieru
3  Najlepšie reklamy Slovenska. Pozrite si výsledky sútaže Zlatý klinec 2015
```

Why am I losing punctuation here? Číny vs. Cíny ...

Why are data shown in grid view of environment var window as follows?

```
1   Amerika je znepokojen� expanziou C�ny v Juhoc�nskom mori
2   P�pe� Franti�ek oznacil palest�nskeho prezidenta za anjela mieru
3   Najlep�ie reklamy Slovenska. Pozrite si v�sledky s�ta�e Zlat� klinec 2015
```

I suggest some encoding problem, but have no idea where to fix this.

Thx for your help.

**Update**

```
#setup
url <- "http://hnonline.sk/rss/1"

#encoding (svk encoding types http://luki.sdf-eu.org/txt/cs-encodings-faq.html)
#encod <- "ISO_8859-2"
#encod <- "latin1"
#encod <- "latin2"
encod <- "UTF-8"

rssFeedContent = xmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = TRUE, encoding = encod)
rssItems <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(xmlRoot(rssFeedContent), 
                                              "//channel//item", 
                                              #sessionEncoding = encod
                                              ), 
                           colClasses = c("character", "character", "character", "character", "character"),
                           homogeneous=TRUE)
```

The problem is, that I am not able to find correct encoding to show all special characters for Slovak language (see: svk encoding types http://luki.sdf-eu.org/txt/cs-encodings-faq.html). Currently some special characters are shown as �

Comment: Hello, as after 40 viewing no one answer was provided, I will add a simple code example showing my problem.

Comment: It works OK on linux, which is able to respect utf-8 encoding according to the locale. This is problematic on Windows.